# Facebook graph api to post photo on wall in perl

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

in perl i am using Facebook::Graph api  to post on user wall as i am having aceess token and plain message is working

```
my $fb = Facebook::Graph->new(
    app_id          => $app_id,
    secret          => $secret,
        );

        $fb->access_token( $access_token );



      $fb->add_post
         ->set_message($message)
         ->set_picture_uri("http://st.pimg.net/perlweb/images/lcamel.vcf3914e.gif")
         ->publish;
```

here message is posted with picture but what i need is instead of giving link in set_picture_uri i want to upload a file from local. Is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to build something on your own to upload file.

But I assume Facebook might have API that asks for user to upload the file.